# Why does my ImageView hide my TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I'm trying to create something like "(combo image) a :66-74 | b :61-65 | c :18-60 | d :0-17", but unfortunately my "d" (number) is missing. I suspect its hidden by my "|" image.
the result is like this: [image]

and my xml is:

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/migdal_combo_mevutahim"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="SelectGroups"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="5pt"
            android:paddingTop="3pt"
            android:weightSum="8" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wizard_1_txt_Group66"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="גיל 66-74:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/migdal_combo_middle_line" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wizard_1_txt_Group60"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="גיל 61-65:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/migdal_combo_middle_line" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wizard_1_txt_Group40"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="גיל 18-60:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/migdal_combo_middle_line" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wizard_1_txt_Group0"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="גיל 0-17:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

can you please tell how to fix my mistake ?
    Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
           <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/migdal_combo_mevutahim"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="SelectGroups"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="5pt"
            android:paddingTop="3pt"
            android:weightSum="8" >
```

to

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/migdal_combo_mevutahim"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="SelectGroups"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="5pt"
            android:paddingTop="3pt"
            android:weightSum="9" >
```

A very small silly mistake.